BUG OF TEXTURE WITH DECOCRAFT
Hi I’ve got a problem with 1.12.2 decocraft, the block textures are bugged and monocolour: they change colour between brown/transparent/white when I move. What do I do?
I've tried reinstalling the mod and PTRLIB, and I've tried playing without shaders or resource packs, but nothing works.
